# Зачем нужны разные php.ini?

Tags: php

Делаю:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Ответ консоли:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Делаю `phpinfo()`

Ответ: Loaded Configuration File `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Почему разные пути показывает? (на самом деле грузится второй)

И почему команда grep не нашла файл php.ini в каталоге apache2?

И зачем нужно много php.ini?

Comment: не много, а два. один для вэб-сервера, другой для работы в консоли.

Comment: @teran бывает и больше, если несколько версий php стоит

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо, кэп! :) можно и под одну версию написать больше конфигов, если надо, но вопрос то явно про отличие cli и вэб

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**с Тостера:**

`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` - служит для настройки PHP, который запускается с помощью Apache

`/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` - служит для настройки PHP, который запускается с помощью консоли

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/php5

Comment: Спасибо, понятно, непонятно только почему grep для веб-версии не нашёл конфиг

Comment: Хм..Честно говоря не знаю. Вместо grep лучше использовать
`locate php.ini`